# AWS S3 "Junk" Files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm brand new to AWS so please excuse my ignorance. I'm getting a bunch (900+) of "junk" files (formatted similar to: 2020-12-08-02-17-54-140126DAE31F68E8) in an S3 bucket I've created. When searching online, I found articles from 2010 & 2011 that discuss these as being "log" files and recommend adjusting settings in CloudTrail but I don't have any trails set up. Appreciate any assistance anyone can provide.

Comment: This does sound like a log file - have you tried to see what is in the file?  Does anyone else have permission to write to the bucket?

Comment: Thanks for the response. No one else has red/write permission. When I click on the file  under "object overview" I get the following: <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>8947C24AC78EDC9B</RequestId>
<HostId>XBUN80GV3roXcOg/Vm0YeXM0jxMMld6Ix4HGg3AiKMGxDXW28D/NNVvZdGR+JnL1haZmcqRUBSA=</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: Is that through the AWS console?

Comment: Yes, through the console.

Comment: I wonder whether it is [Amazon S3 server access logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) files? You can check buckets to see whether this is activated. They certainly aren't "junk" -- they would be log files from _something_.

Comment: Understood. I mean "junk" as in I don't need to see them when I'm going into main objects within buckets. Would you recommend I create a bucket to catch these logs?